# Shared Memory with Dask

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask, shared-memory

I parallelise a CPU-bound task via Dask's starmap, which takes a large nested list and a sparse matrix as read-only inputs. To avoid that the nested list and the sparse matrix are repeatedly copied into the processes, I would like to make both objects accessible via shared memory.   Does Dask provide a Dask-native solution?

I am working on a 64-bit Windows machine, using Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep 3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] and Spyder 4.2.1. As a workaround solution, I already tested using shared memory from the multiprocessing library, which did not work for nested lists and sparse matrices.

In what follows, I present a minimal example to showcase my use-case:

```
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import Client 
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix  
from time import sleep

# Create a nested list
nested_list = [list(range(2)), list(range(3))]

# Create a sparse matrix
sparse_matrix =  lil_matrix((1000, 1000)) 
sparse_matrix[0, :100] = range(100) 
sparse_matrix[1, 100:200] = sparse_matrix[0, :100] 

def toy_function(x, y, z, nested_list, sparse_matrix):
    # After some time compute a sum.
    sleep(10)
    result = x + y + z + sparse_matrix[0, 0] + nested_list[0][0]
    return result

data = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (7, 8, 9), (9, 10, 11)]
b = db.from_sequence(data)

z = b.starmap(toy_function, nested_list = nested_list, sparse_matrix = sparse_matrix).compute()
# From the Dask Dashboard I conclude that nested_list and sparse_matrix are copied into each process.
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pre-distribute these objects with `client.scatter` (depending on your use-case you may not want to have a copy on each worker, in that case you can omit the `broadcast=True` option):

```py
import dask.bag as db
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client 
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix  
from time import sleep
client = Client()

# Create a nested list
nested_list = [list(range(2)), list(range(3))]
nested_list = client.scatter(nested_list, broadcast=True)

# Create a sparse matrix
sparse_matrix =  lil_matrix((1000, 1000)) 
sparse_matrix[0, :100] = range(100) 
sparse_matrix[1, 100:200] = sparse_matrix[0, :100] 
sparse_matrix = client.scatter(sparse_matrix, broadcast=True)

def toy_function(x, y, z, **kwargs):
    nested_list, sparse_matrix = kwargs['nested_list'], kwargs['sparse_matrix']

    # After some time compute a sum.
    sleep(1)
    result = x + y + z + sparse_matrix[0, 0] + nested_list[0][0]
    return result

data = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (7, 8, 9), (9, 10, 11)]
b = db.from_sequence(data)

z = b.starmap(toy_function, nested_list = nested_list, sparse_matrix = sparse_matrix).compute()
print(z)
```

Alternatively, you can also convert these objects into `delayed`, so only a reference to the delayed object is passed. This would mean that instead of the `client.scatter` you will have `dask.delayed` wrappers:

```py
nested_list = dask.delayed(nested_list)
sparse_matrix = dask.delayed(sparse_matrix)
```

Comment: I tested the client.scatter() solution setting `broadcast` to its default value `False`. However, inspecting the task manager and analogously the Dask Dashboard, I concluded that memory is not shared. Analogously for the `dask.delayed` wrapper, I observed that the large nested list was copied into each process. I implemented both solutions, as suggested in the presented code snippet.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. In both snippets what is passed to the function is either a future or a delayed value (both of which are lightweight and do not depend on the size of the underlying object)...